# Ansible: connect to a remote host via proxy

Tags: ansible, remote-server

I'm working on a playbook that needs to connect to a couple of different servers through a proxy.

I was able to test the connection using putty and the proxy.
Basically, went to connections --> proxy, then select HTTP and added the proxy host.

But, I was not able to reproduce it with SSH from the Ansible server.
I tried different ssh commands:

```
ssh -L jumphost.example.org:80 fred@server.example.org -p 443
ssh -J jumphost.example.org:80 fred@server.example.org
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p jumphost.example.org" server.example.org
ssh -tt jumphost.example.org ssh -tt server.example.org
```

I know there are different options that use `nc` but I didn't try them, because its not installed on the server.

Is there any way to connect to the remote host in ansible using the proxy?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?
    - hosts: all
      remote_user: root

```
  tasks:

    - name: Install cobbler
      package:
        name: cobbler
        state: present
      environment:
        http_proxy: http://proxy.example.com:8080
```

from: [playbooks_environment](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html)